# scala play action composition response header

Tags: scala, playframework, http-headers

I am using action composition for api authorization by reading request headers. I want to inject authentication token on response header so client can use it to call API on consecutive calls. So far, I have intercepted the request using action composition, can I set response header before I get to the controller code or only can be done on controller code ?

Can response header be injected in below invokeBlock ?

```
def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: AuthorizedRequest[A] => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = { 
    val requestToken = sessionTokenPair(request)
    requestToken match {
      case Some(token) => { 
        AuthenticationManager.validateAPIToken(token).map { sh =>  
        block(new AuthorizedRequest(sh, request))
        }.getOrElse{
          Future.successful(Forbidden(Json.toJson(
            Error(status = Status.FORBIDDEN,errorCode = 43, message = "Bad Request",developerMessage="Issue")
           )))
        }
      }
      case _ => {
        Future.successful(Forbidden(Json.toJson(
            Error(status = Status.FORBIDDEN,errorCode = 43, message = "Bad Request",developerMessage="Issue")
           )))
      }}
    }
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `invokeBlock` is a great place to do this - certainly no need to repeat yourself in every controller.

In your "success" case, where you have:

```
block(new AuthorizedRequest(sh, request))
```

you are effectively returning the `Future[Result]` that `block()` gives you.
To add extra headers, just `map` over that `Future` and add them using the [handy methods on `Result`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Result):

```
block(new AuthorizedRequest(sh, request)).map { result =>
   result.withHeaders(
     "x-foo" -> "f00", 
     "x-bar" -> "bar")
}
```

Comment: Thank you millhouse worked like a charm. No code repetition i was re-issuing token with new expiry now i can simple abstract away api key validation

Comment: @DipendraAdhikari excellent. I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer. Good luck!